# Secondary postfix instance is not listening

Tags: linux, postfix

I've two postfix instances running on the same server, but just the main IP is listening at port 25.

I can send emails with both instances, each one with his outgoing IP.

But I can't do: telnet hostname2 25 (telnet externalIP2 25 neither).

Both `inet_interfaces` are `localhost, external_IP`

If I do a netstat, I see the external IP of the main postfix listening at port 25, but nothing about the second one.

Any idea? I tried to look any info over internet for hours with no luck...

EDIT: I can confirm the `inet_interfaces` of the secondary instance is doing nothing. The second ip is not listening.

Comment: what is the value of smtp_bind_address in each of the instances (should be in main.cf)? Can you add the output of `ss -lt4p '( sport == :smtp )' ` to the question, if possible running the command as root?

Comment: You also want the `inet_interfaces` to be different for the two instances, you probably want the second one to be just hostname2.